# Who cataloged the ships that visited Alta California?

Tags: naval, colonial-america, transportation, california, age-of-sail

I know I have seen a reference to a comprehensive list of ships that visted Alta California in the Spanish and Mexican eras, but I need help finding it again.

[Here](http://www.sfgenealogy.com/sf/history/hb75yap6.htm) is an incomplete list without any sources, as published in "Seventy-five Years in San Francisco" (1929).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trading vessels on the California coast, 1786-1848, by Adele Ogden](http://www.worldcat.org/title/trading-vessels-on-the-california-coast-1786-1848/oclc/82974084).